# Flyweight VirtualRepeater containing IntegerPicker

Tags: webos, enyo

In my Enyo app, I have a `VirtualRepeater` which produces `Control`s containing various text displays and an `IntegerPicker`.

I have two problems with this repeater:

1) If three rows are produced, clicking on the `IntegerPicker` in rows 1 and 2 brings up the drop-down picker UI over the top of the `IntegerPicker` in row 0.

2) I initialise each `IntegerPicker` with a max value using `setMax()`. However, if three rows are produced, the `IntegerPickers` in rows 0 and 1 will have the same max value as that in row 2.

It looks as if only one `IntegerPicker` is being created and is being used on the first row.

I tried replacing my `VirtualRepeater` with a `Repeater`, and changed my repeater row creation function to return a new instance of the item containing the `IntegerPicker`, instead of returning true. However this produces the error:

warning: enyo.Component.addComponent(): Duplicate component name "itemName" violates unique-name-under-owner rule, replacing existing component in the hash and continuing, but this is an error condition and should be fixed.

It seems that `Repeater`s need their delegates created inline, which seems quite inelegant.

This code sample illustrates the problem:

```
enyo.kind({
   name:"Test",
   kind:enyo.Control,
   components: [
      {
         kind: "VirtualRepeater",
         onSetupRow: "setupRow",
         components: [{
                name: "theIP", kind: "IntegerPicker", min:0
         }]
      }
   ],

   setupRow: function(inSender, inIndex) {
      if (inIndex < 3) {
         this.$.theIP.setMax(inIndex);
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
});
```

How can I create an arbitrary number of `IntegerPicker`s in my app?  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing with theIP in your setupRow function is accessing a specific IntegerPicker itself, which is a child component of the Virtual Repeater. To set the max value of a given IntegerPicker corresponding to the row, give your VirtualRepeater a name attribute, like "PickerList":

```
 kind: "VirtualRepeater",
 onSetupRow: "setupRow",
 name: "PickerList",
 components:[//this should be empty to begin with]
```

Then you can access each row in the repeater like this:

```
setupRow: function(inSender, pickerMax) {

   var newPicker = new IntegerPicker(pickerMax);
   this.$.PickerList.push(newPicker);
```

To get a specific row in the VirtualRepeater you need to do it like this:

```
this.$.PickerList[1];
```

Here is an extended Enyo tutorial which makes use of the VirtualRepeater:
   https://developer.palm.com/content/resources/develop/extended_enyo_tutorial.html